# Google Play Game Services integration fails with "Play Games callback indicates connection failure."

Tags: android-ndk, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have integrated Google Game Services with my NDK game using the minimalist code example.

When starting the app, the authentication fails with this in the logs:

```
V/GamesNativeSDK( 7212): Play Games callback indicates connection failure.
I/GamesNativeSDK( 7212): UI interaction required to connect to Google Play.
I/TeapotNativeActivity( 7212): Sign in finished with a result of -3
I/biplane ( 7212): OnAuthActionFinished
I/biplane ( 7212): You are not logged in!
I/TeapotNativeActivity( 7212): Fetching all blocking
I/TeapotNativeActivity( 7212): --------------------------------------------------------------
I/TeapotNativeActivity( 7212): Fetching all nonblocking
I/TeapotNativeActivity( 7212): --------------------------------------------------------------
I/TeapotNativeActivity( 7212): Achievement response status: -3
```

I've performed all the steps outlined in the online documentation, including:

- Created a game service in Google Play Developer Console and linked two apps.
- Linked app with Debug key
- Linker app with Release key
- Took the app-id from linked apps (same id for both linked apps) and put it in res/values/ids.xml
- Created leaderboards, and put their IDs in res/values/game-ids.xml
- Added tag to my AndroidManifest.xml with name="com.google.android.gms.games.APP_ID" and value="@string/app_id"
- Downloaded latest update of Game Services app.
- Listed myself as test user.

I am not sure which message is the original error, and which is a symptom.
"Connection Failure" or "UI Interaction required".

Note that in the Developer Console, the two linked apps are listed as 'Ready to publish.'

The source code I use is a verbatim copy of StateManager.cpp from the c++ code examples, and in my android_main I have copied the example code snippet as well:

```
// gpg-cpp:  Here we create the callback on auth operations
auto callback = [&](gpg::AuthOperation op, gpg::AuthStatus status) {
    LOGI("OnAuthActionFinished");
    if (IsSuccess(status)) {
        LOGI("You are logged in!");
    } else {
        LOGI("You are not logged in!");
    }
    //engine.animating = 1;
};

if (state->savedState != NULL)
{
    // We are starting with a previous saved state; restore from it.
    engine.state = *(struct saved_state*)state->savedState;
    LOGI("Restored state");
}
else
{
    LOGI( "No saved state to restore." );
    gpg::AndroidPlatformConfiguration platform_configuration;
    platform_configuration.SetActivity(state->activity->clazz);
    // Now, create the game service (see StateManager.cpp) and pass in callback
    StateManager::InitServices(platform_configuration, NULL, callback);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So, it turns out that this behaviour is intended:
Auto logins (upon service start) are supposed to fail if you have never logged in before.

You need to do a user initiated login first, with:

```
game_services_->StartAuthorizationUI();
```

...before subsequent auto logins will succeed.

Also note that there are a lot of errors on the console, which do not seem to interfere with the proper functioning of the google play game service.

```
E/GamesNativeSDK(12369): Exception in dalvik/system/DexClassLoader.loadClass: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.android.gms.games.NativeSdkEntryPoints" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/data/com.steenriver.Biplane/app_.gpg.classloader/4da25210572e7e07ea67142ded62c42e.jar"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib, /system/lib]].
W/dalvikvm(12369): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/d; (148)
W/dalvikvm(12369): Link of class 'Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/d;' failed
I/dalvikvm(12369): Could not find method com.google.android.gms.common.api.d.a, referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.gl
W/dalvikvm(12369): VFY: unable to resolve static method 3084: Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/d;.a (Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;)Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/d;
D/dalvikvm(12369): VFY: replacing opcode 0x71 at 0x0002
W/dalvikvm(12369): VFY: unable to find class referenced in signature (Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;)
E/dalvikvm(12369): Could not find class 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity', referenced from method com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient$Builder.enableAutoManage
W/dalvikvm(12369): VFY: unable to resolve check-cast 149 (Landroid/support/v4/app/FragmentActivity;) in Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$Builder;
D/dalvikvm(12369): VFY: replacing opcode 0x1f at 0x0010
```

One last note: Strangely, I've also seen the 'user interaction required' error when trying to login without a network connection.

Comment: Note that that "result -3" may also happen if you are missing a linked application in Google Play console. You need two linked apps: one with debug key, and one with release key.

Comment: When should I execute the StartAuthorizationUI()? when the AuthFinished callback has been executed and returned -3?

Comment: @ViktorSehr I call it when the user taps the Google Login button.